# Failed to open stream - DOM and File_Put_Contents

Tags: php, url, dom, simplexml, fopen

I have a cronjob which download different files from different URLs and modifies the data. The curios thing is that everything works well and now I wanted to add two more URLs but with those URLs I have some problems...

But I just do not why... All URLs (8) use the same functions. But only the 2 new URLs are throwing that error. I'm not allowed to provide the URLs here but I can say you that I can download both URLs in my Chrome Browser.

I load one URL with a DOM:

```
function fetchXmlDocument($url, $output, $dom = null){
    if (!$dom instanceof DOMDocument) {
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
    }

    $dom->load($url);
    $dom->save($output);
    return $dom;
}
```

Here I get this error:

> DOMDocument::load(http://myurl.de): failed to open stream: HTTP
>   request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
>
> DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity
>   ...

The other URL is loaded with fopen:

```
function fetchCsvDocument($url, $output){
    return file_put_contents($output, fopen($url, 'r'));
}
```

Here I get this error:

> fopen(http://myurl.de):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service
>   Temporarily Unavailable

Does somebody knows how I can fix this error?
I just don't get why I can download the URLs with my browser but PHP tells me that 403 or even 503.

The other files I download with those functions and modify don't throws this errors...?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: I suggest to use [`libxml_set_streams_context`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php) to set the User Agent. If it doesn't work, try to load your file using `cURL` that offers more options and returns more informations. More informations about [http status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden:

The server most likely detects that the request does not come from a browser (and maybe doesn't like that) and/or the server wants some session state (which the browser sends, but your code probably not).

To see what's being sent between browser and server, in chrome, hit F12 and select Network and click on the links to see the HTTP headers.

503 Service Temporarily Unavailable could be the same reason (if that url also works from the browser).

Also check http vs. https.

Another reason could be that the url is not properly [encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) (i.e. replace space with `%20`) which the browser does automatically